# Angular 4 Ngif directive how to use

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular-ng-if

I want to know why I have to use this directive `<div *ngIf="show">Text to show</div>` when I have to show some text/form that comes from http call.
I know if I don't use it angular gives me some error like:

> var a is undefined

because when i am displaying html the varible binded doesn't contain any value.
But is it a best practice? Is always necessary when we have situation like this?
And are there better ways to do this?

Comment: This explains quite well, and mentions the ngIf and the "pros and cons" of using safe navigation operator vs ngIf. https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths

Comment: You don't need to necessarily handle it with `ngIf`, you just need to make sure your component can deal with the fact that the value isn't going to be there until the HTTP call completes. For example, if `this.text` on your component gets set after a HTTP call, rather than leaving it undefined you could set it to an empty string, or some other default value.

Comment: So if I don't want to initialize every objects I need ngIf? @JoeClay

Answer (score 1):

You can just define the variable with some initial default value to which you have binding in your HTML template. Refer to the official documentation https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf. Let me know if you have any further query.

Answer (score 1):

When the HTML loads on the page, the value of `Text to show` will be undefined as the HTTP call probably wont have returned a response for you to set it.

when the HTTP call returns, and you then set your `Text to show` it is no longer undefined and can be shown in HTML.

So here there are two options:

1. Set the `Text to show` to a default value, even "" if you like. When the HTTP call returns, then overwrite this value, and the angular binding will update the view.
2. Use the *ngIf directive, telling angular not to render that HTML yet (and thus doesn't need those undefined variables). This is useful for if you have multiple variables on a page, which rely on HTTP calls. Once the calls all return the data you need and all of your variables are set, you can set your variable `show` to true, allowing the HTML to render and the variables to be shown.

The official docs are here: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngif

What I commonly end up with is a `showPage` variable, and a
`<div *ngIf="showPage"></div>` wrapper on the html for the page. 
When i have all the data i need for the page, i then set `showPage` to true.

Answer (score 1):

ngif expression resulting value won’t just be the boolean true or false

but will instead be a object value that you may want to reference easily.

```
  things = {
 car: 'Honda',
 shoes: 'Nike',
 shirt: 'Tom Ford',
 watch: 'Timex'
 };
```

typical use: if 'things' exist, display 'there is things'. if 'things' is undefined. display nothing. 'things' could be boolean true/false, 'things' could be any other type, could be just a variable of a object.

```
<div *ngIf="things">
     there is things
 </div>
```

for example:

```
 <div *ngIf="things.car; else noCar">
  Nice car!
 </div>

<ng-template #noCar>
   Call a Uber.
</ng-template>

 <!-- Nice car ! -->
```

anthoer example:

```
<div *ngIf="things.car; let car">
   Nice {{ car }}!
 </div>
<!-- Nice Honda! -->
```

[ngif template](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-reactive-templates/)

[ngif angular 4](https://alligator.io/angular/ngif-new-features-angular4/)